# Functioning, up-to-date Emacs mode for TypeScript

Tags: emacs, typescript

Is there a reasonably functional, up-to-date, Emacs mode for TypeScript? There doesn't seem to be an official one, or least an official one that is actively updated.

There is a Microsoft one [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/10/01/sublime-text-vi-emacs-typescript-enabled.aspx), but it is old and doesn't incorporate the latest language changes (e.g. `boolean` as a keyword in addition to `bool`). [This one](https://github.com/eugeneiiim/homedir/blob/master/emacs_stuff/typescript-mode.el) looks similar, as does [this one](https://github.com/aki2o/emacs-tss/blob/master/typescript.el) which claims to be more sophisticated.

All suffer from the  following problem. In the example below, `borderRadius` is coloured differently from `borderWidth` and `fontSize`, presumably because the syntax colouring isn't coping properly with multiple variables introduced by a single `var` declaration.

```
var borderRadius: number = 4,
    borderWidth: number = 2,
    fontSize: number = 9;
```

Comment: I searched several month ago and was forced to conclude that there isn't one. I'm not sure about the licensing model Microsoft used to release its original mode, but maybe it would be possible to work on it to improve it. (Though, most likely, not).

Comment: https://github.com/aki2o/emacs-tss/blob/master/README.md seems to have had its last commit 17 days ago. Maybe you can still get in touch with the author.

Comment: @user797257 I don't think you searched very hard.

Answer (score 8):

The up-to-date modes are the following: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/TypeScript

### Tide

It is in [MELPA](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Melpa) so easy to install.

- ElDoc
- Auto complete
- Flycheck
- Jump to definition, Jump to type definition
- Find occurrences
- Rename symbol
- Imenu
- Compile On Save
- Highlight Identifiers
- Code Fixes

screencast:

[image]

### Error checker

There is also an [error checker](https://github.com/Simplify/flycheck-typescript-tslint), for flycheck, that uses tslint.

[image]

### Spacemacs integration

Spacemacs has a Typescript layer: https://spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/typescript/README.html

it also includes an optional code formatter (https://github.com/vvakame/typescript-formatter).

### see also

there is also emacs-tss that uses typescript-tools, but it is less active than the others. See the [wiki](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/TypeScript).

Answer (score 2):

[emacs-tss](https://github.com/aki2o/emacs-tss) includes [a major mode](https://github.com/aki2o/emacs-tss/blob/master/typescript.el), as you note. Since this package is maintained and available on MELPA, I suggest you use that and file these bugs there.

Answer (score 1):

For the minimalist, there's also [`typescript.el`](https://github.com/emacs-typescript/typescript.el). It

> is a self-contained, lightweight and minimalist major-mode focused on providing basic font-lock/syntax-highlighting and indentation for Typescript syntax, without any external dependencies.

It supports `tsc` and `tslint`.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one TypeScript IDE for emacs, and its name is [tide](https://github.com/ananthakumaran/tide).